# Retrieve Points inside a Map Polygon Telerik

Tags: sql-server, telerik, polygon, spatial, spatial-query

I'm trying to get the points inside a polygon with an spatial query, the thing is that the points and the polygon are in the same SQL Table, I'm attaching a picture with the result of a [Select Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjmgx.png) where you can see that the last 3 records are the polygons that contains points.

I've tried this with one point but it won't work because I need a list with the names of the polygons and the points inside of it in a spatial query.

```
    DECLARE @POI geography;  
    DECLARE @POLYGON geography;  
    SET @POI = (SELECT TOP 1 GEO FROM POI WHERE LAYERID <> 1026);
    SET @POLYGON = (SELECT TOP 1 GEO FROM POI WHERE LAYERID = 1026);
    SELECT @POLYGON.STContains(@POI);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do:

```
select [point].ID, [poly].ID
from GEO as [point]
join GEO as [poly]
   on [point].LAYERID <> 1026
   and [poly].LAYERID = 1026
   and [poly].GEO.STContains([poly].GEO]) = 1;
```

Of course, once you've done the matching, you can `select` anything you want (I chose the respective IDs).